# Filtering an array of objects with elements of array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

```
var ClubsArray = [[Any]]() 
var filteredClubs = [[Any]]()

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
        filteredClubs = ClubsArray.filter { (club: Club) -> Bool in
            return club.Name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        cardTableView.reloadData()
    }

 func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
        filteredClubs = ClubsArray.filter { (club: Club) -> Bool in
            return club.Name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        cardTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I'm trying to filter an array of objects that contains the searched text, but I get this error message:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type '([Any]) throws -> Bool'

Comment: Not related to your question but there is no need to lowercase your string. There is a method called `localizedStandardContains` exactly for for this purpose. It is case and diacritic insensitive. Btw it is Swift naming convention to name your variables and constants starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: 1. Show how `ClubsArray` is declared. Looks like it is declared as `[Any]` instead of `[Club]`. 2. It's best practice to start variable and property names with lowercase letters. Class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase letters. Following such practices makes your code easier to read for others. 3. What does this have to do with UIKit?

Comment: Please edit your question and show your `filteredClubs` and your `ClubsArray` declarations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to filter an array:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
    filteredClubs = ClubsArray.filter { $0.Name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) as! Bool}

    cardTableView.reloadData()
}
```

You will get a warning but you have to ignore this warning. Hope this works.